# Arraylist populated from jsonarray request

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a method which returns an arraylist, and it is populated from jsonarray
jsonrequest works fine, but when i call the method the arraylist returns a size of 0 even it is populated.
Below is the code, what am i doing wrong

```
private ArrayList<String> queryRes(String url, String searchString) {


    final ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();


    client.get(url + searchString,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                    for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                   mylist.add(i, jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("id"));

                        //Check if it is added to the list
                        Log.d("Try: ", mylist.get(i));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                }
            });

    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: put debug at mylist.add(i, jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("id")); and check it.

Comment: Async call gives result after your return statement. The only possible solution to this problem is, don't return anything. Just create your own listener method and onSuccess call this method with your arraylist.

Comment: AsynHttp call is done in another thread, so mylist will be returned even before the network call is completed so use an interface to supply back the result where you want

Comment: please  do log at  jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("id")

Comment: @YasirTahir and George Thomas, i will give a try. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

onSuccess() called when you get the response means AsynHttp call is done in another thread so your return statement call before onSucess thats why size is 0.

you can verify it on debugger

my suggestion is call a method from onSuccess() so you will get Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing everything in a single class

```
public void populateList(String url, String searchString)
{
 final ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();


    client.get(url + searchString,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                    for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                   mylist.add(i, jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("id"));

                        //Check if it is added to the list
                        Log.d("Try: ", mylist.get(i));
                    }

              onListPopulated(myList);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                }
            });

}
```

A method to do something with the list

```
public void onListPopulated(ArrayList<String> list)
{
//do something with the list
}
```

Comment: Well, it does work this way, but i really need to return an arraylist, because i need to add it to another arraylist, returned from another method